# Add class for number_with_precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I have a code, which shows price:

```
def value
  h.number_with_precision(object.value, precision: 2,strip_insignificant_zeros: false)
end
```

And i put this value in `haml`: `%b= #{number.value}`

For example: showing price "1234.02" inside `<b/>` and I need some styles to ".02". How to put precision inside `span`?

EDIT:
Ruby string have formatter built in. No need to use any class.
Just use `"%.2f" % #{number.value}`

Comment: It's fine to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) but you should do so by posting an answer instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split number.value with '.' as separator, and use it like

```
full_value = number.value.to_s.split('.')

haml: %b #{full_value[0]}.
        %span #{full_value[1]}
```

Answer (score -1):

As you are not stripping insignificant zeroes you will always have 3 digits at the end you need to format (assuming you're including the decimal place).

You can do

```
number.value.to_s[0..-4]
```

Which will give you all characters in the string apart from the last 3, and then

```
number.value.to_s.last(3)
```

To return the part you want to format separately

If you don't want to format the decimal point, and just need the last 2 characters separated:

```
number.value.to_s[0..-3]
number.value.to_s.last(2)
```

You can then format these as needed